# localAddress at camel-http4

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to define localAddress on camel-http4 component. According to the documentation [camel-htt4](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) this could be done using the parameter httpClient.XXX where XXX is the parameter found in [RequestConfig.Builder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html)

So I would expect that something like the following would work:

```
.to("http4://{{hostname}}:{{port}}/{{method}}?throwExceptionOnFailure=false&httpClient.localAddress='123.123.22.22'")
```

I am checking with netstat on linux using 2 virtual interfaces, but without luck.

Comment: Try without the single quotes around the ip

Comment: thank you, this was the problem. Initially I had tried without quotes but probably something else was wrong in my configuration and test setup.